# AngularJS Service Delays to send the data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm getting the data in services but I have received the data as *Undefined*. My AngularJS Service returns the data but I received as *Undefined*.

My Service code:

```
myApp.service("studentinfo", function ($http) {
  var studentlist = [];

  this.GetStudentList = function () {

    $.getJSON("/Home/GetStudentsList", function (data) {
      if (data.Result == "OK") {
        studentlist = data.Data;
      }
      else {
        studentlist = [];
      }
    }).complete(function() {
      return studentlist;
    });
  };
});
```

My Controller Code:

```
myApp.controller("studentcontroller", function ($scope, $http, studentinfo) {
  $scope.StudentList = [];

  function LoadStudentRecord(){
    $scope.StudentList = studentinfo.GetStudentList();
  }

  LoadStudentRecord();
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the data correctly.. I think i'm directly called a method in contoller (studentinfo.GetStudentList();) and received a input is the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing a couple of things up here, as mentioned:

1. You seem to be using jQuery ( `$.getJSON` )- where I recommend you try to stay with the Angular `$http` ( which you are injecting by the way ). So try to use $http.GET ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ).
2. Keep in mind that this returns a promise. You probably do want to return a promise from your service, so that you can decide how to handle in case of failure, in your controller.
3. I recommend using a different way to instantiate your services and controller, see my example below. That allows you to minify your code later.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.service('studentservice', ['$http', function ($http) {
    getStudentList = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetStudentsList');
    };
    return {
        getStudentList: getStudentList
    }
}]);

app.controller('studentcontroller', ['$scope', 'studentservice', function ($scope, studentservice) {
    $scope.StudentList = [];

    function LoadStudentRecord() {
        $scope.StudentList = studentservice.getStudentList()
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 $scope.StudentList = data;
        })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log(data)
        });
    }
    LoadStudentRecord();
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks spike... The way is defined by service is wrong... now i understood... Thanks onceagain...

Comment: Really helps a lot... I'm a beginner for angularjs

Answer (score 3):

I see you inject $http but you don't use it. Replace the jQuery method with $http. $http will return a promise and the in the controller you can update your model with any of the promise method (then, catch, finally)

Comment: And even the return is inside a method the complete method. the service is not returning nothing. Tha's why you get undefined

Comment: yes, have a look at the docs. you can use any method post, get, patch, delete... And you can specify the type of data that your app expects. I think that the default is json.

Comment: myApp.service("studentinfo", function ($http) {

    var studentlist = [];

    this.GetStudentList = function () {

        var responsepromise = $http.get("/Home/GetStudentsList", function (data) {
            if (data.Result == "OK") {
                studentlist = data.Data;
            }
            else {
                studentlist = [];
            }
        });

        return studentlist;

    };

}); // I have tried this also.. but still it returns the result first then only it calls the http mehtod

Answer (score 1):

```
function studentFunction ($http) {
  var studentlist = [];
  this.GetStudentList = function () {
     return $http.get("/Home/GetStudentsList");
  };

}

myApp.service("studentinfo",  studentFunction);
myApp.controller("studentcontroller", function ($scope, studentinfo) {

  $scope.StudentList = [];

  function LoadStudentRecord(){
    studentinfo.GetStudentList().then(function (respoonse) {
    $scope.StudentList = respoonse;
  });
}

LoadStudentRecord();
```

});

The service should looks something like that. You use the promise in your controller.